# Clear kafka topics for unit testing

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka

I need to perform unit testing on a kafka application avoiding third-party libraries.

My problem right now is that I would like to clear all the topics between tests but I don't know how.

This is my temporary solution: commit every message produced after each test and put all test consumers in the same consumer group.

```
override protected def afterEach():Unit={
    val cleanerConsumer= newConsumer(Seq.empty)
    val topics=cleanerConsumer.listTopics()
    println("pulisco")
    cleanerConsumer.subscribe(topics.keySet())
    cleanerConsumer.poll(100)
    cleanerConsumer.commitSync()
    cleanerConsumer.close()
}
```

This doesn't work though and I don't know why.

For example, when I create a new consumer inside a test, `messages` contains the messages produced in the previous test.

```
val consumerProbe = newConsumer(SMSGatewayTopic)

val messages = consumerProbe.poll(1000)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Kafka is a persistent message store and it lets the consumer decide the offset for starting the consumption. You will just have to remember the last offset you dropped at and start consuming after that.

Comment: Try to use an embedded broker as for example here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/FanoutIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Java? As a result it turns up in searches that are very java specific. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also embed a Kafka/Zookeeper instances in your test sources, to have more controller over such isolated services.

```
trait Kafka { self: ZooKeeper =>
  Kafka.start()
}

object Kafka {
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
  import kafka.server.KafkaServer

  @volatile private var started = false

  lazy val logDir = java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("kafka-log").toFile

  lazy val kafkaServer: KafkaServer = {
    val config = com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.
      load(this.getClass.getClassLoader)

    val (host, port) = {
      val (h, p) = config.getString("kafka.servers").span(_ != ':')
      h -> p.drop(1).toInt
    }

    val serverConf = new kafka.server.KafkaConfig({
      val props = new java.util.Properties()
      props.put("port", port.toString)
      props.put("broker.id", port.toString)
      props.put("log.dir", logDir.getAbsolutePath)

      props.put(
        "zookeeper.connect",
        s"localhost:${config getInt "test.zookeeper.port"}"
      )

      props
    })

    new KafkaServer(serverConf)
  }

  def start(): Unit = if (!started) {
    try {
      kafkaServer.startup()
      started = true
    } catch {
      case err: Throwable =>
        println(s"fails to start Kafka: ${err.getMessage}")
        throw err
    }
  }

  def stop(): Unit = try {
    if (started) kafkaServer.shutdown()
  } finally {
    FileUtil.fullyDelete(logDir)
  }
}

trait ZooKeeper {
  ZooKeeper.start()
}

object ZooKeeper {
  import java.nio.file.Files
  import java.net.InetSocketAddress
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
  import org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer
  import org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory

  @volatile private var started = false
  lazy val logDir = Files.createTempDirectory("zk-log").toFile
  lazy val snapshotDir = Files.createTempDirectory("zk-snapshots").toFile

  lazy val (zkServer, zkFactory) = {
    val srv = new ZooKeeperServer(
      snapshotDir, logDir, 500
    )

    val config = com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.
      load(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val port = config.getInt("test.zookeeper.port")

    srv -> ServerCnxnFactory.createFactory(
      new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port), 1024
    )
  }

  def start(): Unit = if (!zkServer.isRunning) {
    try {
      zkFactory.startup(zkServer)

      started = true

      while (!zkServer.isRunning) {
        Thread.sleep(500)
      }
    } catch {
      case err: Throwable =>
        println(s"fails to start ZooKeeper: ${err.getMessage}")
        throw err
    }
  }

  def stop(): Unit = try {
    if (started) zkFactory.shutdown()
  } finally {
    try { FileUtil.fullyDelete(logDir) } catch { case _: Throwable => () }
    FileUtil.fullyDelete(snapshotDir)
  }
}
```

The tests classes can `extends Kafka with ZooKeeper` to ensure this available.

If the test JVM is not forked, `Tests.Cleanup` in SBT `testOptions in Test` setting can be used to stop the embedded services after testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, you simply recreate all topics before your tests. For example, this is the way kafka tests create/delete topics:

[Kafka repository on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/admin/DeleteTopicTest.scala)